# Overridden method in derived class

Tags: c#, overriding, abstract-class

I have an abstract class with an abstract method and this class is inherited by over 100 other classes where we override this virtual method.
Now there is a slight change in business requirement and we need to do a check before calling the overridden method. I know I can put a check in each of the 100 class but that doesn't seems to be an elegant way where change is required in all derived classes.

Is there a better approach to handle this change?

```
public abstract class BaseFunction
{
    public abstract Result FunctionCall();
}

public class Function1 : BaseFuction
{
    public override Result FunctionCall()
    {
        //business logic
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make the abstract base method virtual and put your check there, but then you would have to call your base method from the derived ones. I'm afraid there's no possibility to not change your derived methods.

Comment: I think there is no way to do that (unless you are willing to use something like [`Fody`](https://github.com/Fody/Fody)) without changing manually either all implementing classes or all places where this method is called outside those classes. If you are willing to manually change one of those then you can use [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) - basically what @wohlstad suggested.

Comment: either add the change on all derived classes, or implement a validator and use it in which you process these classes. So, these classes will be passed through that validator before processing to the final results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a wrapper method to your base class like `FunctionCallWithCheck`, that will perform the check, and then call the original abstract method `FunctionCall`.

In order to customize the check, I put it in a virtual method with a default implementation that you can override (if needed) in derived classes.

**Note:** You will have to replace all you **calls** to `FunctionCall`, with `FunctionCallWithCheck` (in the code that uses all these classes).
Of course this is a good approach only if there aren't too many places where you **call** `FunctionCall` (you didn't supply info about that).

```
public abstract class BaseFunction
{
    // Default check. You can override it in derived classes if needed.
    public virtual bool Check()
    {
        return true;    // put your conditions here
    }

    public int FunctionCallWithCheck()
    {
        if (Check())
        {
            return FunctionCall();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    protected abstract int FunctionCall();
};

public class Function1 : BaseFunction
{
    protected override int FunctionCall()
    {
        //business logic
        return 1;
    }
};
```

I replaced the return type to `int` since you did not supply the defintion for `Result`. I assume it has some default value in case the conditions for calling `FunctionCall` were not met (instead of the `-1` value that I used for that).

**Update:**
As @KlausGütter commented, you can make `FunctionCall` into a `protected` method (rather than `public`), in order to get a compiler error if you accidently called it instead of `FunctionCallWithCheck`. I updated my code above.
If you'd rather not change it because of the many derived classes, you can also keep it `public` (but you'll loose the compiler's protection).

Comment: When does `FunctionCallWithCheck()` get called? Wouldn't you have to call it in derived classes - what he is trying to avoid?

Comment: @user11909 I added a clarification to my answer.